# Styling Twitter's new Embedded Timeline

Tags: javascript, css, api, twitter

Since Twitters V1 Embedded timeline was deprecated a few days a go I've had to move over to version 2, I have managed to style the timeline to as close as possible as I want it using the directions on the Twitter Developers site.

The final thing I can't work out how to change is the font. Does any one know how I can chage the font family and colour that is being used on the timeline?

Here is my code so far:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" 
data-chrome="noheader noborders transparent nofooter"
data-link-color="#299efe"
data-dnt="true"
data-tweet-limit="3"
data-widget-id="private"
href="https://twitter.com/private"></a>

<script>
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}
}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Comment: Your code so far is an empty link with a lot of attributes? I don't get it. Otherwise CSS properties for what you're asking are `font-family` and `color`. Do you need anything else, and if yes: what?

Comment: This is how you have to implement the new twitter embedded timeline on your site since version 1 is deprecated, as well as the javascript obviously, which I will now add to the question. Twitter doesn't allow for a style attribute, so I'm asking if there is anyway to change this?